# Android Studio 3.4.1 doesn't reflect the changes of my app design

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing the menu of my app with colors, fonts, styles. The problem is that when I've made some text-color changes and I run my app in the emulator, the emulator doesn't reflect the changes that I've made. 
I have some buttons with Android-resource-file xml files where I have made the style of the buttons. And then I changed the text-color of the buttons but emulator doesn't reflect the changes.
Does anybody can help me? Thanks!

I'm running the app in Android Studio 3.4.1. I've tried cleaning cache from File>Invalidate Cache/Restart

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/presentaciones"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/presentaciones"
            android:text="@string/presentaciones"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
```

Note that text color is background_light (white)

Background file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#FF9800"></solid>
    <stroke android:color="#FFFF" android:width="2dp"></stroke>
    <size android:width="150dp" android:height="150dp"></size>
</shape>
```

I expect that the buttons have text-color white, actually the emulator is showing with text black despite the code is right

Comment: Try to restart the emulator and maybe upload the app to a real device if you have one. It worked for me previously